# pytorch vgg model test on one image

Tags: python, pytorch

I've trained a vgg model, this is how I transformed the test data

```
test_transform_2= transforms.Compose([transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224), 
                                     transforms.ToTensor()])

test_data = datasets.ImageFolder(test_dir, transform=test_transform_2)
```

the model's finished training now I want to test it on a single image

```
from scipy import misc

test_image = misc.imread('flower_data/valid/1/image_06739.jpg')
vgg16(torch.from_numpy(test_image))
```

### Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-b83587325fea> in <module>
----> 1 vgg16(torch.from_numpy(test_image))

c:\users\sam\mydocu~1\code\envs\data-science\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    475             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    476         else:
--> 477             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    478         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    479             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

c:\users\sam\mydocu~1\code\envs\data-science\lib\site-packages\torchvision\models\vgg.py in forward(self, x)
     40 
     41     def forward(self, x):
---> 42         x = self.features(x)
     43         x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
     44         x = self.classifier(x)

c:\users\sam\mydocu~1\code\envs\data-science\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    475             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    476         else:
--> 477             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    478         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    479             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

c:\users\sam\mydocu~1\code\envs\data-science\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\container.py in forward(self, input)
     89     def forward(self, input):
     90         for module in self._modules.values():
---> 91             input = module(input)
     92         return input
     93 

c:\users\sam\mydocu~1\code\envs\data-science\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    475             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    476         else:
--> 477             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    478         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    479             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

c:\users\sam\mydocu~1\code\envs\data-science\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py in forward(self, input)
    299     def forward(self, input):
    300         return F.conv2d(input, self.weight, self.bias, self.stride,
--> 301                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    302 
    303 

RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [64, 3, 3, 3], but got input of size [628, 500, 3] instead
```

I can tell I need to shape the input, however I don't know how to based on the way it seems to expect the input to be inform of a batch.

Comment: Would `vgg16(torch.from_numpy(test_image).view(1, 628, 500, 3)` move you forward?

Comment: @dedObed this returns this error `RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 3, 3, 3], expected input[1, 628, 500, 3] to have 3 channels, but got 628 channels instead`

Comment: using you're suggestion `vgg16(torch.from_numpy(test_image).view(1, 628, 500, 3))`

Comment: Great, so it does move you forward. So refer please to the answer by Jatentaki, he deals with the full reshaping needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image is `[h, w, 3]` where 3 means the rgb channel, and pytorch expects `[b, 3, h, w]` where `b` is batch size. So you can reshape it by calling do that by calling `reshaped = img.permute(2, 0, 1).unsqueeze(0)`. I think there is also a utility function for that somewhere, but I can't find it right now.

So in your case

```
tensor = torch.from_numpy(test_image)
reshaped = tensor.permute(2, 0 1).unsqueeze(0)
your_result = vgg16(reshaped)
```

Comment: you've got it but I can't use this suggestion since it's not part of scipy or torch_from_numpy

Comment: Updated my answer above

Comment: Thanks, tried it and I get this error, `RuntimeError: thnn_conv2d_forward is not implemented for type torch.ByteTensor`

Comment: It means your image is of type `torch.uint8` (standard 255 valued rgb) and should be `torch.float32`. You probably want to add another line `floatified = reshaped.to(torch.float32) / 255.` and call vgg16 on that. But that's just a guess of the normalization convention you're using, it needs to be aligned with how the network was trained. In other words: `reshaped.to(torch.float32)` will make the message go away but not necessarily make the net produce sensible predictions

Comment: That works, just one more thing, I get this error `RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [1 x 145920], m2: [25088 x 4096] at c:\new-builder_3\win-wheel\pytorch\aten\src\th\generic/THTensorMath.cpp:2070` believe it's because I forgot to resize it to 224 by 224. Could you guide me on that?

Comment: You're right. You can use the standard slicing syntax `corner = reshaped[:, :, :224, :224]`